# Is it possible to hide cartesian area from the 'derived information' of the identify features tool in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I'd like to remove the cartesian area calculation in the *derived information* section of the **identify features** tool, since it sometimes confuses some colleagues to have two values there. Couldn't find any clues with google though.

Comment: I looked through QGIS documentation and settings, and apparently, it's not possible using the GUI. One might still be able to do it with Python (not me, though...)